# UIView's shadow been covered by other view, how to solve it?

Tags: ios, uikit

I added a shadow to NavigationBar, but it won't shows up because it been covered by UIView that directly below it[image: NavigationBar's shadow covered by other UIViews]. After I add a constraint that make UIView have 10px spacing to navigation bar, I can see navigation bar's shadow[image: After separate NavigationBar from UIView, shadow shows up.]. How do I fix this to let shadow show over UIView? [image: How I add shadow.][image: Storyboard Hierachy]

**Update:** I tried to put shadow adding code in viewDidLayoutSubview, doesn't work at all.

**Update:** I uploaded a screenshot that show how I add shadow.

**Update:** I didn't embedded this in navigation controller. This is a navigation bar that I dragged in from Interface Builder.

**Update:** I uploaded a screenshot of my storyboard hierarchy.

Comment: move your shadow view to top of view hierarchy, try with `self.view.bringSubview(toFront: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar)!)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't help at all... Seems like I have to bring that shadow to the front instead of it's belonging view?

Comment: Can you post how you are adding your shadow?

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: OK, but your view is contained in your NavigationBar? in titleView?

Comment: Your navigationBar is a real navigationBar or a custom navigation bar?

Comment: I didn't embedded my view in navigation controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom navigation bar is in a lower z index in your views hierarchy so you need bring your custom NavigationBar to front, you can also manually move your view in your storyboard to achieve this, dragging your `NavigationBar` to the bottom of your views hierarchy, just below of your button "Got it" in this example

or by code doing this in your `viewDidLoad`

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.yourCustomNavigationBar)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! But I didn't embedded my view in navigation controller.

Comment: @YH.Liang then your problem is easy to solve, how is called your custom navigation header View?

Comment: Sorry that I don't quite understand what you means by "Called your custom navigation header view"? Can you elaborate on that a little bit?

Comment: can you post your storyboard view hierarchy? to see what is wrong? @YH.Liang

Comment: I uploaded one, please check it out.

Comment: @YH.Liang drag your navigation bar to the bottom of your views hierarchy, problem solved, just below of your button Got it

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much! It's really counter intuitive that the bottom one is the the most front one...

Comment: One more question, how can you edit the priority of elements in StackView?  If you drag one element down, it also change it's position.

Comment: You mean the z index in a Stackview? @YH.Liang

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151758/discussion-between-yh-liang-and-reinier-melian).